# how to copy any file through the terminal and paste it out (X11),

Tags: linux, terminal, vifm

I would like to copy any file (audio, video, text, image) through the terminal and paste it in the browser. like ctr + c and ctrl + v.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-the-clipboard-in-bash-script) post.